# Two Distinct Arc Length Parameterisations

Tags: vector-analysis, arc-length

$f$ and $g$ are two arc length parameterisations of a regular simple curve $C$, then prove either $f(s) = g(e+s)$ or $f(s) = g(e-s)\; \forall s$ for some constant $e$.

---

Intuitively I can understand as the only possible difference between $f$ and $g$ could be the endpoints of the (interval) domain (and both intervals, i.e., domain have the same length). This is true since $\| f' \| = 1 =\| g' \|$.
What I mean is:
$$f: I=[a,b] \rightarrow C$$
$$g: J=[c,d] \rightarrow C$$
$$l(I) = l(J)$$
$$\text{Arc len} = s(t) = \int_a^t \| f' \|ds = \int_c^t \| g'\|ds$$

---

For  the proof, I am thinking in terms of defining $\phi: I \rightarrow J$ followed by using chain rule and fundamental theorem of calculus. But I can't seem to write a formal proof.

Comment: You have not used that they are regular simple curves. You can use that $f$ and $g$ are injective so by checking the preimage of some fixed point on the curve we will get unique $s_0$ and $s_1$ such that $f(s_0)=g(s_1)$. This allows us to calculate $c = s_1 - s_0$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Kind of, from inverse function theorem and above f, g def i can show there is a bijection between I and J. Then using your hint and the fact that the curve is regular and simple can i directly conclude f(s) = g(c+s)? It really would be much better if you could provide a full/partial answer.